# Sum all positive integers in a bash array

Tags: bash, arithmetic

How can I sum all positive integers in a bash array.

Here is my code:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

arr=(2 43 -1 -33 24 12 -6)

for (( i = 0; i < ${#arr[@]}; ++i )); do
  if (( arr[i] > 0 )); then
    sum=`expr $sum + $i`
  fi
done
echo "$sum"
```

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to select the positive numbers, rather than the negative ones

```
if (( arr[i] > 0 )); then
```

then you need to sum the array *values* rather than the indices

```
sum=`expr $sum + ${arr[i]}`
```

or (since you are already using the `(( ... ))` arithmetic evaluation syntax elsewhere)

```
sum=$((sum + arr[i]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Actually that was my typo just now :/ it was correct in my system.

Comment: Or `(( sum += arr[i] ))`

Comment: @АндрейОганов If one of the answers solved your issue, please take a moment to [accept it](//$$SITEURL/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on [the checkmark on the left](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203101). That will mark the question as answered and is the way that thanks are conveyed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Thank you very much ! 
So, what's wrong in this ? 
```sum=0 
for i in "${arr[@]}" do if (( "i" -gt 0 )); then sum =$psum+"$i" elif (( "i" -lt 0 )); then sum$nsum+"$i" fi done echo "positive = $psum" 
echo "negative = $nsum" ```

Comment: Thank you ! And how can I do it right ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a trick to replace all array elements starting (`#`) with a `-` with nothing.
This way you can skip the check in the loop.

```
$ arr=( 2 43 -1 -33 24 12 -6 )
$ echo "${arr[@]/#-*}"
2 43   24 12
```

And the modified script:

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=( 2 43 -1 -33 24 12 -6 )

sum=0
for i in "${arr[@]/#-*}"; do
  (( sum+=i ))
done

echo "$sum"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my new attempt:

```bsh
# 2+43+24+12=81
sum=0
arr=( 2 43 -1 -33 24 12 -6 )
arr=("${arr[@]/-*/0}")
sum=$(IFS=+; echo "$(( ${arr[*]} ))" )

echo "$sum"
81
```

Comment: or perhaps....`echo $(( $(printf "%s+"  ${arr[@]/#-*/0})"0" ))`

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, you can also use `awk` to do the looping for you

```
arr=(2 43 -1 -33 24 12 -6); 
sum=$(echo ${arr[*]} | awk '
    BEGIN{RS=" "}
    $0>0{sum+=$0}
    END{print sum}');
echo $sum
81
```

Handy if you want to do something more than integer math

```
arr=(2 43 -1 -33 24 12 -6); 
sqrt=$(echo ${arr[*]} | awk '
    BEGIN{RS=" "}
    $0>0{sum+=$0}
    END{printf "%.2f", sum^0.5}');
echo $sqrt
9.00
```